# Use of unresolved identifier error when calling array in my extension code

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, drop-down-menu, xcode9-beta

I am trying to create a fairly simple drop down menu for which I have created an array with some strings to be displayed. I am not sure where I have gone wrong but the array "rList" does not get recognised when I write the extension code to add the array onto a UITableView to be displayed in the drop down. An unresolved identifier error shows up at the extension code where "rList" is called. Also note I am running on Xcode 9 beta not sure if there have been changes in some syntax that I may have missed. Appreciate any help I can get on this!

Cheers

(Heres the code)

```
import UIKit


    class MainViewController: UIViewController {



        @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

        @IBOutlet weak var dropDownButton: UIButton!

        var rList = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.tableView.isHidden = true
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        }


        @IBAction func dropDownButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
            if tableView.isHidden {
            animate(toggle: true)
            } else {
                animate(toggle: false)
            }
        }


        func  animate(toggle:Bool) {
            if toggle {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                    self.tableView.isHidden = false
                }
            } else {
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {

                    self.tableView.isHidden = true
                }
              }
            }
          }
```

Now for my extension code

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return rList.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = rList[indexPath.row]
    return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are extending `ViewController` (which is the default empty view controller provided by an app template) instead of `MainViewController`. `ViewController` in its template form does not have `rList` as member, thus the error.

Change your extension to:

```
extension MainViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: Oh man, I have been at this for way too long. Thank you so much haha totally missed that!

Comment: Also, when I run the app, none of the contents of my array is displayed on the drop down menu. Do you think you can tell where I am going wrong?

Comment: in viewDidLoad set tableView delegates (datasource and delegate) as self

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry still new to swift, how do I go about doing this?

Comment: wait nvm I found out how! Thanks again!

Comment: App crashes when I set tableView.delegate(and data source) to self.

Comment: "tableView.delegate = self " When I comment the 2 lines out the app works fine but the output cannot be seen

Comment: I placed a break point in my extension code and realised when I tap the button, the drop down loads without ever running the extension code. Could that be the problem?

Comment: are you sure tableView is connected in the storyboard?

Comment: tableView is connected to my MainViewController. Have I connected it incorrectly?

Comment: The button and tableview is actually configured as a stack view on my main story board. Could that be causing this?

Comment: use the debugger and check if tableView is nil at that point when you set its delegates